# Bootstrap sidebar - Collapsed by default? (Metronic HTML template)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap sidebar and want to have this sidebar to be collapsed by default when my server delivers my webpage. The status at the moment is the normal default bootstrap sidebar which is extended and not collapsed. I will put my sidebar code below.

I already tried to toggle the collapsed status of the bootstrap sidebar by jQuery, however, with this solution the user sees that the sidebar gets toggled and this doesn't look so nice. Simply by executing this line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sidebar-menu-toggle").click();
});
```

Also, if the user reloads the site multiple times it is very annoying to have the sidebar being collapsed after the page has loaded.

This is my sidebar wrapper code so far:

```
<div class="page-sidebar-wrapper">
    <div id="page-sidebar-menu" class="page-sidebar navbar-collapse collapse">    
        <ul id="page-sidebar-menu-ul" class="page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed page-sidebar-menu-light " data-keep-expanded="false" data-auto-scroll="true" data-slide-speed="200" style="padding-top: 40px">
            <li class="sidebar-toggler-wrapper hide">
                <div class="sidebar-toggler">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link "> My Menu </a>
                <span class="selected"></span>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link "> My Menu </a>
                <span class="selected"></span>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link "> My Menu </a>
                <span class="selected"></span>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my toggle button places in the header (which disappears on toggle):

```
<div id="sidebar-menu-toggle" class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler">
    <span></span>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

As you can see the `<a href.. id="page-sidebar-menu"` is targeting the `navbar-collapse` class. So, I think it has something to do with it but I am not sure.

What's also good to know is the fact when I press the toggle button to collapse my sidebar, the element with the id `page-sidebar-menu-ul` is changing the classes.

From:

```
page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed page-sidebar-menu-light
```

To:

```
page-sidebar-menu  page-header-fixed page-sidebar-menu-light page-sidebar-menu-closed
```

This is the only inline CSS HTML code which I can see. I already tried to change it and deliver my page by default with this class but it is not changing anything.

I should also tell you that I am using the Metronic HTML template and I think this is also interacting with the bootstrap sidebar somehow.. but I am not quite sure cause my JS skills are not that good...

Here you can find a working demo of the sidebar:
https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=builder&demo=default

The reason why I cannot give you guys a working demo is that the `.js` and `.css` files. They are not public and I cannot find any CDN which is hosting these files. Probably cause they are not free and you have to buy them. So, this is the best what I can give you.

My target is to change the HTML and CSS code so it delivers the page with a collapsed sidebar by default. Just to remind you again :)

Do you guys have any idea on how to do this?

Kind regards and thank you!

Comment: If you go to https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?page=builder. Inside *Left Aside* tab there is an option for *Default Minimized Aside*. Then you can export the customized template.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. But I cannot copy the entire page.. There needs to be a workaround. At least somehow..

Answer (score 2):

Since this is from almost two years ago, I'm not sure if what I used is applicable to OPs case. But in case there are more people with this issue using versions similar to 7.0.5 of Metronic theme, my way of fixing it was:

In the body tag of your theme just add the class aside-minimize. That's it (or it was for me haha). In my case I already had the class aside-secondary-enabled, which just enables the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an old post but for version 8 you can add this attribute to the `<body>` tag

`data-kt-aside-minimize="on"`